# Euclidean tangent cone implies Riemannian manifold

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, metric-spaces

[It is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultralimit#Examples) that given a Riemannian manifold, then the tangent cone (as a metric space) at any point $p$ is isometric to the tangent space at $p$, with the metric given by the metric tensor.

Is there a converse, or an additional condition to have a converse, in the following form?

> Given a metric space $X$ such that the tangent cone at any point is a Euclidean space of dimension $n$, and (possibly additional condition), then $X$ is a Riemannian manifold of dimension $n$.

Comment: e.g., you may assume that $X$ has bounded curvature (since "at the end" it will). Then $X$ is a manifold by known theorems (see "Alexandrov spaces").

Comment: @valeri So is there an actual statement "A metric space with curvature bounded below is a Riemannian manifold iff its tangent cone is an Euclidean vector space"?

Comment: note, that if $X$ has bounded (below and above here) curvature and no boundary, then you may have tangent cone=euclidean space for free. Then, if I remember correctly, yes, it was proved that Al.space with bounded curv is ($C^{1,\alpha}$ ?) manifold. Can not help with references though :( So, bounded curvature is a very strong condition, you might like smth else.

Comment: According to Burago-Burago-Ivanov (see Theorem 10.10.13) The result @valeri mentioned is due to Nikolaev (the proof is not given, but a reference is given to V. Berestovskii and I. Nikolaev, Multidimensional generalized Riemannian spaces,
in Geometry IV. Non-regular Riemannian geometry. Encyclopaedia of Mathematical
Sciences, Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1993, 165–244.)

Comment: I also wonder if the issue is regularity. In [Otsu and Shioya](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1274133) they have that an Alexandrov space such that the tangent cone is everywhere Euclidean is $C^0$-Riemannian (see Remark 3 on page 631). Note that the result of Nikolaev in my previous comment gives that the manifold has a $C^3$ atlas and the metric is $W^{2,p}$, so has better regularity.

Comment: Let $X$ be any Riemannian manifold, and $x$ a point. Choose a sequence $(x_n)$ with $d(x_n,x)=2^{-n}$. Let $V_n$ be a subset contained in the ball of radius $2^{-2^{n}}$ around $x_n$. Then it is immediate that the tangent cone of $Y=X\smallsetminus \bigcup V_n$ at $x$ is the same as that of $(X,x)$. But (if every $V_n$ is nonempty), $Y$ is not a topological manifold at $X$. If moreover $V_n$ are chosen closed (e.g., the whole closed ball), $X$ is Riemannian at every other point, so every tangent space is **isometric** to a Euclidean space ("is a Euclidean space" is an ambiguous formulation)

Answer (score 13):

To provide some context the subsets of a Euclidean space that can be approximated by affine planes on every scale are known as Reifenberg-flat sets after E. R. Reifenberg who proved in the 1960s that such sets are bi-Holder to a Euclidean space. There is a substantial literature on the subject (search on "Reifenberg-flat").

Now regarding your specific question: T. Colding and A. Naber construct in  [Lower Ricci Curvature, Branching, and Bi-Lipschitz Structure of Uniform Reifenberg Spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2184)  a metric space $Y$ such that

1. The tangent cones of $Y$ are all isometric to $\mathbb R^n$ (which by an earlier work of J. Cheeger and Colding implies that $Y$ is bi-Holder homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$).
2. Every bounded set of $Y$ is bi-Lipschitz embeddable in some Euclidean space.
3. There is no homeomorphism of $Y$ onto $\mathbb R^n$ such that the pullback geometry is induced by some $C^{0,\beta}$ Riemannian metric where $0<\beta<1$.

To show (3) they prove that geodesic in $Y$ branch in the sense of Theorem 1.3 of the linked paper.

Moreover, $Y$ occurs ``in nature'' as a pointed Gromov-Hausdorff limit of a noncollapsing sequence of Riemannian $n$-manifolds with a common lower bound on Ricci curvature.

I am not sure whether the metric on $Y$ can be induced by a $C^0$ Riemannian metric but in any case branching of geodesics is not the property a decent $C^0$ metric should be proud of.